# JBehave Eclipse Plugin do not react on Ctrl+F

Tags: eclipse, search, keyboard-shortcuts, jbehave

I'm using JBehave and its companion plugin with Eclipse, which is fine, but there is something that makes me mad, it DO NOT react when I hit Ctrl+F, which I expect to open the search dialog box.

I crawled a bit on the internet but except some messages on the mail archive (https://www.mail-archive.com/user@jbehave.codehaus.org/msg02382.html) stating the same problem, I did not found any answer until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a way to circumvent the problem, and I feel it may be of some use to other people so here it is :

I opened the Preferences > Keys and copied the "Find and replace text".

On the copy, I chose to set "When" to "JBehave Story Editor", and "Binding" to "Ctrl+F"... and surprise ! It then showed me that it conflicted with a "Format Table" command in this particular "When" context.

Curiously, this mapping is not shown when I enter "Ctrl+F" in the filter text area...
Actually, the whole "JBehave Story Editor" *When* context seems totally invisible in the Keys list.

Anyway, I somehow fixed the problem by setting "Ctrl+Shift+F" to the duplicated "Find and Replace" with *When* set to "JBehave Story Editor", which works fine.

By the way, I discovered that when selecting a JBehave table and hitting Ctrl+F, it actually pretty-print it with appropriate padding in the cells to make the column align nicely :)

**UPDATE**

Actually I found how make "JBehave Story Editor" shortcuts appear in the list :
In Preferences > Keys, hit Filters... and uncheck "Filter uncategorized commands".

Then "Format Table" appears, and it is then possible to remap it to Ctrl+Shift+F for example.
The "Find and replace text" duplication is no more needed :)